# in typescript How to write http service in function

Tags: angular2-routing

Here i know hou to use http service in this way but how can i write service when its in function Like

```
export class studentController {

        GetStudentData() {
         constructor(http: Http) {
          http.get('api/Employee').subscribe(result => {

                this.student = result.json();
            })
        }
    }


export class StudentMastre {
    stdID: Number;
    stdName: string;
    email: string;
    Phone: string;
    Address: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a service to request the data and get, then use the service inside the component to get the data,

Your sample service should be,

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
 c(): Observable<StudentMastre[]> {
        let wikiUrl = return this.http
            .get('api/Employee')
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }
private extractData(res: Response) {
        let data = res.json();
        return data;
    }

    private handleErrors (error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

then in your component,

```
this.sampleService.
this.categoryService.getCategoriesService().subscribe(students=> {
    this.students= students;
}, error => this.errorMessage = error);
```